# Can't render a quad using VBOs

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to render a quad with vertex buffer objects in LWJGL.

```
[5, 5, 6]
[6, 5, 6]
[6, 6, 6]
[5, 6, 6]
```

It kind of works:

[image]

But it only renders a triangle (the cube is rendered using immediate mode), and I'm not sure if its something wrong with the vertices or the tex coords (or something else entirely).

Block.java: (x=5, y=5, z=5)

```
private final Texture top;

public void render() {
    top.render(x, y, z + 1, x, y + 1, z + 1, x + 1, y + 1, z + 1, x + 1, y, z + 1);
}
```

Texture.java:

```
    public final TextureResource textureResource;

    public final int width, height;

    private final int texID;
    private FloatBuffer vBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer tBuffer;

    private boolean changed = true;

    private IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
    private final int vHandle;
    private final int tHandle;

    public void render(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2, float x3, float y3, float z3, float x4, float y4, float z4) {
        updateBuffers3D(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4);
        textureResource.render(texID, vBuffer, tBuffer, changed, vHandle, tHandle, Color.WHITE, 3);
    }

    private void updateBuffers3D(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2, float x3, float y3, float z3, float x4, float y4, float z4) {
        FloatBuffer tempVertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(12);
        FloatBuffer tempTextureCoordsBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);

        tempVertexBuffer.clear();
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.clear();

        System.out.println(x1 + ", " + y1 + ", " + z1 + " | " + x2 + ", " + y2 + ", " + z2 + " | " + x3 + ", " + y3 + ", " + z3 + " | " + x4 + ", " + y4 + ", " + z4);

        tempVertexBuffer.put(x1).put(y1).put(z1);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(x2).put(y2).put(z2);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(x3).put(y3).put(z3);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(x4).put(y4).put(z4);
        /*tempVertexBuffer.put(x1).put(x2).put(x3).put(x4);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(y1).put(y2).put(y3).put(y4);
        tempVertexBuffer.put(z1).put(z2).put(z3).put(z4);*/

        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(0).put(0);
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(0).put(1);
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(1).put(1);
        tempTextureCoordsBuffer.put(1).put(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (vBuffer.get(i) != tempVertexBuffer.get(i)) {
                vBuffer.clear();
                tempVertexBuffer.flip();
                vBuffer.put(tempVertexBuffer);
                vBuffer.flip();
                changed = true;
                break;
            } else {
                changed = false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (tBuffer.get(i) != tempTextureCoordsBuffer.get(i) || changed) {
                tBuffer.clear();
                tempTextureCoordsBuffer.flip();
                tBuffer.put(tempTextureCoordsBuffer);
                tBuffer.flip();
                changed = true;
                break;
            } else {
                changed = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

TextureResource.java:

```
    private void use(int texID, ReadableColor color) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glColor4f((float) color.getRed() / 255f, (float) color.getGreen() / 255f, (float) color.getBlue() / 255f, (float) color.getAlpha() / 255f);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    }

    private void endUse() {
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public void render(int texID, FloatBuffer vBuffer, FloatBuffer tBuffer, boolean changed, int vHandle, int tHandle, ReadableColor color, int size) {
        if (!loaded) {
            return;
        }

        use(texID, color);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
        if (changed) {
            glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
        }
        glVertexPointer(size, GL_FLOAT, 8, 0L);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, tHandle);
        if (changed) {
            glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, tBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
        }
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 8, 0L);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        endUse();
    }
```

Any ideas? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot make heads or tails of the code you are using to declare the vertices in this example, but I can tell you that if the 4 vertices are not all in the same plane then this kind of thing can happen. Technically the results are undefined, but in some implementations what happens is the first triangle of a triangulated quad/polygon is drawn and everything else that is not in the same plane is lost to the void. It is one of the reasons quads and polygon primitives are deprecated, rasterizing primitives with points that do not all lie in the same plane is hard work.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman That is very interesting, I did not know that, although it might not apply to this situation since I am pretty sure the Z coord is always 6. But maybe somehow?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thank you very much! It now works, seems that was the problem. I would not have thought of that at all, I thought a stride of 0 meant opengl has to calculate the stride on its own and it would be slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon closer inspection, I believe the stride argument in your calls to `glVertexPointer (...)` and `glTexCoordPointer (...)` are to blame. It should be **0** and not **8**, because these are two tightly-packed buffers, rather than a buffer that interleaves vertex and texture coordinates. And even if you were using an interleaved buffer, the stride would be 8 + 12 = **20**.

```
glVertexPointer(size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

[...]

glTexCoordPointer(size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

When you use a stride of **8**, you overrun your vertex array after drawing only the second vertex.

Comment: :) You are very attentive!